# What natural monoidal structure and braiding exists on the category of modules of the convolution algebra of an action groupoid?

Tags: category-theory, representation-theory, hopf-algebras, monoidal-categories, groupoids

Let $S$ be a set with an action $\triangleright$ of a finite group $G$. The [action groupoid](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/action+groupoid) $S // G$ has as objects the set $S$, and the morphisms from $s_1$ to $s_2$ are just the $g \in G$ that satisfy $g \triangleright s_1 = s_2$.

It is easy to see that representation category of finite connected groupoids is equivalent to that of the stabiliser group of any object ([see this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/16481/representation-of-groupoids)). But the representation theory of the [convolution algebra](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/category+algebra) seems to have more interesting extra structure, apparently. Let $\mathbb{C}[S//G]$ be the algebra spanned by the morphisms from $S//G$, and $ g_1 \cdot g_2$ is the composite of the morphisms if they're composable, and 0 otherwise.

Now, already when taking the groupoid with two objects $A, B$ and two nontrivial morphisms $f: A \to B$ and $f^{-1}$, something interesting is happening: The groupoid is itself equivalent to the trivial category, but its convolution algebra is 2$\times$2 complex matrices, $M_\mathbb{C}(2)$.
The representation category of $M_\mathbb{C}(2)$ is equivalent to $\mathrm{Vect}$, but not monoidally equivalent: The simple object tensor squares to two copies of itself. The reason behind this seems to be the coproduct on the algebra: It is not $\Delta f = f \otimes f$ like in the group case, but $\Delta f = 1_A \otimes f + f \otimes 1_B$. I'm assuming that in general for $f : A \to B$, a formula like this must hold:
$$\Delta f = \sum_{\substack{C \in \operatorname{ob} S//G \\ g: A \to C \\ h: C \to B \\ hg = f}} g \otimes h$$
So in general, we should have a Hopf algebra, with an antipode coming from the inverse. The coproduct can even be noncommutative.

One example is particularly striking: Let $G //_{\text{ad}} G$ be the action groupoid of $G$ acting on itself with the adjoint action. Then the convolution algebra is the [Drinfel'd double](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Drinfel'd+double) $D(G)$! Its representations are the Drinfel'd centre of $\operatorname{Rep}G$, which has the modular braiding.

**Has the braided monoidal structure on the representations of a groupoid been studied? Is there a natural $R$-matrix on the convolution algebra? When is the braiding modular?**

Edit: It occurs to me that in many cases (like $G//_\text{ad} H$ for a subgroup $H$), the algebra is not Hopf, but only weak Hopf, i.e. the unit $\eta = \sum_{s \in \operatorname{ob} S // G} 1_s$ is not always preserved by the coproduct. Does that mean that the category of modules is multifusion?

Comment: It seems more likely that this comultiplication is actually part of a [Frobenius algebra structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_algebra).